# dplyr: applying calculations with differing column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create the following formula:

```
Interest expense / (Total Debt(for all years)) / # number of years
```

The data looks like the following;

```
                                GE2017    GE2016    GE2015    GE2014
Interest Expense              -2753000  -2026000  -1706000  -1579000
Long Term Debt               108575000 105080000 144659000 186596000
Short/Current Long Term Debt 134591000 136211000 197602000 261424000
Total_Debt                   243166000 241291000 342261000 448020000
                             GOOG2017 GOOG2016 GOOG2015 GOOG2014
Interest Expense              -109000  -124000  -104000  -101000
Long Term Debt                3943000  3935000  1995000  2992000
Short/Current Long Term Debt  3969000  3935000  7648000  8015000
Total_Debt                    7912000  7870000  9643000 11007000
                             NVDA2018 NVDA2017 NVDA2016 NVDA2015
Interest Expense               -61000   -58000   -47000   -46000
Long Term Debt                1985000  1985000     7000  1384000
Short/Current Long Term Debt  2000000  2791000  1434000  1398000
Total_Debt                    3985000  4776000  1441000  2782000
```

That is, for `GE`, I am trying to take interest expense for the latest year `-2753000` divide this by the average of `Total Debt` for all 4 years for `GE`.

So;

`-2753000 / AVERAGE(243166000 + 241291000 + 342261000 + 448020000) = 0.0086`

However I am running into problems with `group_by()` when taking the average since `GE` and the other firms have different column names due to the different years.

```
    cost_of_debt %>%
      t() %>%
      data.frame() %>%
      rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
      group_by(rn)
#Calcualtion here
```

Secondly; If possible, I would like to do the same calculation as above but use only the last two years of each firm.

`-2753000 / AVERAGE(243166000 + 241291000) = 0.01136`

Would perhaps a `grepl` function work here?

I have a vector called `symbols`.

`symbols <- c("NVDA", "GOOG", "GE")`

Data:

```
cost_of_debt <- structure(list(GE2017 = c(-2753000, 108575000, 134591000, 243166000
), GE2016 = c(-2026000, 105080000, 136211000, 241291000), GE2015 = c(-1706000, 
144659000, 197602000, 342261000), GE2014 = c(-1579000, 186596000, 
261424000, 448020000), GOOG2017 = c(-109000, 3943000, 3969000, 
7912000), GOOG2016 = c(-124000, 3935000, 3935000, 7870000), GOOG2015 = c(-104000, 
1995000, 7648000, 9643000), GOOG2014 = c(-101000, 2992000, 8015000, 
11007000), NVDA2018 = c(-61000, 1985000, 2e+06, 3985000), NVDA2017 = c(-58000, 
1985000, 2791000, 4776000), NVDA2016 = c(-47000, 7000, 1434000, 
1441000), NVDA2015 = c(-46000, 1384000, 1398000, 2782000)), .Names = c("GE2017", 
"GE2016", "GE2015", "GE2014", "GOOG2017", "GOOG2016", "GOOG2015", 
"GOOG2014", "NVDA2018", "NVDA2017", "NVDA2016", "NVDA2015"), row.names = c("Interest Expense", 
"Long Term Debt", "Short/Current Long Term Debt", "Total_Debt"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For the first case, you dont need the group_by i.le. `cost_of_debt %>%
+       t() %>%
+       data.frame() %>%
+       rownames_to_column('rn') %>% mutate(New = Interest.Expense/Total_Debt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, after creating row names as a column (`rownames_to_column` - from `tibble`), separate that to 'firm' and 'year' by splitting at the junction between the start of the 'year' and the end of the firm, name, grouped by 'firm', create a 'New' column by taking the proportion of 'Interest.Expense' with the `mean` value of 'Total_Debt'.  Then, we can `arrange` by 'year', get the `mean` of the last two 'Total_Debt' for each 'firm' and divide with 'Interest.Expense

```
library(dplyr)
 cost_of_debt %>%
  t() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn')  %>%
  separate(rn, into = c("firm", "year"),
          "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  mutate(New = Interest.Expense/mean(Total_Debt)) %>%
  arrange(firm, year) %>%
  mutate(NewLast = Interest.Expense/mean(tail(Total_Debt, 2)))
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! I am only interested in the final periods for each firm so `2017` for `GE` and `GOOG` and `2018` for `NVDA`. I will extract the final periods into a new ´df´. Thanks again!

Comment: @user113156  You can do a `filter` or just `summarise`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clean your data first so that it is easier to understand what is an observation and what is a variable. Google tidy data :) Here is my solution. First I make the data tidy, then the calculations are straightforward.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), class = "data.frame")
# Clean and make the data tidy
cost_of_debt <- cost_of_debt %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "indicator") %>% 
  mutate(indicator = str_replace_all(indicator, regex("\\s|\\/"), "_")) %>% 
  gather(k, value, -indicator) %>% 
  separate(k, into = c("company", "year"), -4) %>% 
  spread(indicator, value) %>% 
  rename_all(tolower)
```

**Results in the data looking like this:**

```
   company year  interest_expense long_term_debt short_current_long_term_debt total_debt
   <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>                        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 GE      2014          -1579000      186596000                    261424000  448020000
 2 GE      2015          -1706000      144659000                    197602000  342261000
 3 GE      2016          -2026000      105080000                    136211000  241291000
 4 GE      2017          -2753000      108575000                    134591000  243166000
 5 GOOG    2014           -101000        2992000                      8015000   11007000
```

**Then we can answer your question:**

```
cost_of_debt <- cost_of_debt %>%
  group_by(company) %>% 
  mutate(int_over_totdept4 = interest_expense / mean(total_debt),
         int_over_totdept2 = interest_expense / mean(total_debt[year %in% c("2017", "2016")]))
```

**Which gives a dataframe (with your new varibles furthest to the right):**

```
       company year  interest_expense long_term_debt short_current_long_term_debt total_debt int_over_totdept4 int_over_totdept2
   <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>                        <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 GE      2014          -1579000      186596000                    261424000  448020000          -0.00495          -0.00652
 2 GE      2015          -1706000      144659000                    197602000  342261000          -0.00535          -0.00704
 3 GE      2016          -2026000      105080000                    136211000  241291000          -0.00636          -0.00836
 4 GE      2017          -2753000      108575000                    134591000  243166000          -0.00864          -0.0114 
 5 GOOG    2014           -101000        2992000                      8015000   11007000          -0.0111           -0.0128
```

**And if you want the summarized form of your questions:**

```
# First question:
cost_of_debt %>% filter(company == "GE", year == "2017") %>% select(company, year, int_over_totdept4)

# Second question:
cost_of_debt %>% filter(year == "2017") %>% select(company, year, int_over_totdept2)
```